# UIWebView with buttons

Tags: button, uiwebview

before my question i would like to mention that i have been searching for this answer and you guys have led me to understand programming better in general considering the fact i just started learning and kind of struggling since i can't understand written tutorials. :(

Anywho. I am trying to have three buttons on my app each loading different URL's. I understand how to do this with a Tab Controller and honestly i understood how to use them by following one of the tutorials posted here. I came accross a very very strange problem in that and it was that in Tab Controllers, the SecondViewController would be unadjusted to the screen if i added the missing constraints. I couldn't figure out why so i thought to myself that it could be possible to load one URL in one UIWebView but still keep their state of where ever this person is on the page.

Could someone show me an example of how it is done? - Loading URL's via buttons to ONE UIWebView?

extra info: the web app is suppose to be a Show Portal for episodes, and the second button or one of the buttons will have a list of episodes by years, on which the user selects years and then months and then the list of episodes for that month are displayed.

I apologize if i broke a rule.

Thank you!!!